# The term 'remove-distributiongroupmember' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

What are the modules that has to be imported for this error in powershell ?

> The term 'remove-distributiongroupmember' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Exchange Online or on Premises?

Comment: On Premises....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj984289(v=exchg.160).aspx)

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session

#Your code here

Remove-PSSession $Session
```

[Connect to Exchange servers using remote PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335083(v=exchg.160).aspx)

Note: Substitute `mailbox01.contoso.com` for your own exchange server.

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://mailbox01.contoso.com/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
Import-PSSession $Session

#Your code here

Remove-PSSession $Session
```

Comment: I get this error . "The WinRM client received an HTTP status 
code of 440 from the remote WS-Management service." Any Change that needs to be done from the server end ?

Comment: You need to [Enable PSRemoting](https://4sysops.com/archives/enable-powershell-remoting/), it's a different process on a domain or workgroup, that link covers both.